# ASP.NET. - Display shared folder image in img element

Tags: c#, networking

I have a webpage which, amongst other things, displays a file that is built differently by user. This files have previously been created and saved in a remote folder from my webpage itself, so the webpage does have access to the folder (since it previously saved files there).

However, when retrieving those files (.jpeg) and placing them as the src for  tags in html, the images don't appear, and I get the error `Not allowed to load local resource: file://{IP_Address}/{FolderPath}/{Filename}.jpeg` on console.

My image displays fine if the URL is on my local machine, but I need to deploy this on production, and it would be beneficial to use the files in the shared folder rather than in another place due to the access users have on that particular folder, and things would be easy to change and manage since the users are already used to that folder and its files and subfolders.

**DETAILS**

The shared folder is not a subfolder of my site root, it is on a different server within the same network.

I originally store in the remote folder with:

```
var decodedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(SharedFolderURL, decodedImage);
```

Comment: How do you store the images in the remote folder? Is this remote folder a subfolder of your site root?

Comment: Does your url given in src-attribute of the img element start with file:// ? If so, what about serving the image via http/https ?

Comment: I added some details to my question with some more info. And the src does NOT start with "file://" in the HTML when I inspect the page, but it does appear with that prefix in the console error. If I copy that same "src" and paste in in the browser, it correctly shows me the picture. I'll look into how to do it with HTTP/HTTPS for the mean time, I haven't done something like that before.